# Android WebView ajax request interception

Tags: android, ajax, webview

I would like to intercept ajax call from WebView, add extra data to the url, and continue with the request as usual:

For example: change `http://localhost:5000/doSomething` to

`http://localhost:5000/doSomething?secret=my_secret`

and then pass the request for the web server.

I didn't succeeded doing that with shouldInterceptRequest